# Number of distinct prime ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

> How many distinct prime ideals are there for $\mathbb Q[x]/(x^5 - 1)$?

I've got $x^5 - 1$ as a reducible polynomial in $\mathbb Q[x]$. Also $x^5 - 1 =(x-1)(x^4 + x^3 +x^2 + x + 1)$. Here $(x^4 + x^3 +x^2 + x + 1)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb Q[x]$. Is it possible to say anything from this?

Comment: Can you write your quotient ring as the product of two fields? (The factorisation you provided might be useful)

Comment: As a general observation, the prime ideals of $R/I$ are in one-to-one correspondence with the prime ideals of $R$ which contain $I$ (here $R$ is a commutative ring with unity and $I$ an ideal of $R$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that  $(x-1,\,x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)=(1)$. Moreover, since $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is a PID, $$(x-1)\cap(x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)=(x-1)\cdot(x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)=(x^5-1)$$

Hence, by Chinese Remainder Theorem,

$$\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^5-1)\cong{\mathbb{Q}[x]\over(x-1)}\times{\mathbb{Q}[x]\over(x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)}\cong\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}[\zeta_5]$$

But now you can use the characterisation of ideals of a product of rings and the fact that the two factors are fields...

Comment: What if we ask about prime ideala of $Q\[x\] \over \(x^3\) $ ?

Comment: @PranitaGupta They are in bijective correspondence with the prime ideals in $\Bbb Q[x]$ which contain $\sqrt{(x^3)}=(x)$, and thus...

Answer (score 4):

If I am not mistaken, your ring is isomorphic to $\mathbf{Q} \times \mathbf{Q}(\zeta)$ where $\zeta$ is a primitive fith root of unity.  Any ideal in this product ring is of the form I $\times$ S, where I is an ideal in the first component, and S in the second component. But the two components are fields! What can you then say?

Comment: Short and Perfect, I got it. $\mathbf{Q} \times {0} ,{0} \times \mathbf{Q}(\zeta)$ are those.will $\mathbf{Q} \times \mathbf{Q}(\zeta)$ and ${0}\times{0}$ will also be there?

Comment: Yes, usually, ideals are allowed to be the trivial ideal and the whole ring.

Comment: Ok but they both are not prime, Right?

Comment: Ah, I misread the question!....you are right!

Comment: Yes thank you..I was having trouble with this ...

Comment: What if we ask about prime ideals of $Q\[x\] \over \(x^3\) $ ? What will happen after applying Chinese reminder theorem?

Comment: It will be easier here to use the correspondence theorem!

Answer (score 4):

The prime ideals of $\mathbb Q[x]/(x^5-1)$ are of the form $P/(x^5-1)$ with $P\subset\mathbb Q[x]$ a prime ideal containing $x^5-1$. Since $\mathbb Q[x]$ is a principal ideal domain, $P=(p)$ with $p\in\mathbb Q[x]$ an irreducible (monic) polynomial. From $(x^5-1)\subseteq(p)$ we get $p\mid x^5-1$. It follows now that $p=x-1$ or $p=x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$, so there are exactly *two* prime ideals satisfying the requirement.